# Binary Search Tree in Java

Tags: java, tree

Please give me some feedback on how I could make it better or simpler.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

    private static TreeNode root;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
        root = bst.addItem(root, 10);
        bst.addItem(root, 2);
        bst.addItem(root, 6);
        bst.addItem(root, 3);
        bst.addItem(root, 1);
        bst.addItem(root, 15);
        bst.addItem(root, 12);
        bst.addItem(root, 16);

        System.out.println("** Print BST PRE ORDER **");

        bst.printPreOrderTree(root);

        System.out.println("** Print BST IN ORDER **");

        bst.printInOrderTree(root);

        System.out.println("** Print BST POST ORDER **");

        bst.printPostOrderTree(root);
    }

    private TreeNode addItem(TreeNode root, int item) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new TreeNode(null, item, null);
            return root;
        } else {
            if (item < root.element) {
                if (root.left == null) {
                    TreeNode node = addItem(root.left, item);
                    root.left = node;
                } else {
                    addItem(root.left, item);
                }
            } else if (item > root.element) {
                if (root.right == null) {
                    TreeNode node = addItem(root.right, item);
                    root.right = node;
                } else {
                    addItem(root.right, item);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Duplicate Item");
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    private void printPreOrderTree(TreeNode root) {
        if (root != null) {
            System.out.println(root.element);
            printPreOrderTree(root.left);
            printPreOrderTree(root.right);
        }
    }

    private void printInOrderTree(TreeNode root) {
        if (root != null) {
            printInOrderTree(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.element);
            printInOrderTree(root.right);
        }
    }

    private void printPostOrderTree(TreeNode root) {
        if (root != null) {
            printPostOrderTree(root.left);
            printPostOrderTree(root.right);
            System.out.println(root.element);
        }
    }

    private static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        int element;
        TreeNode right;

        protected TreeNode(TreeNode left, int element, TreeNode right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.element = element;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `static` vs instance

Your variable `root` should probably not be `static`. Instead, it should be an `instance` variable so you could have multiple `BinarySearchTree`s in a single program.

## `node` vs `root`

In most places, your naming of `node` vs `root` is good.
In some places, I found it a bit misleading: In `printPreOrderTree()`, `printInOrderTree()` and `printPostOrderTree()` I'd rather call it `node` than `root`. I'd use `root` only for that type of node for which the system has no parent.

## `element` vs `item` (vs `data`?)

I think you can get rid of one of these terms and only use the other. I'd use `item` and dismiss `element`. I find `element` too abstract, the term could also be a supertype of node. I think `item` describes the payload of a node better than `element`.
But then again, maybe simply `data` would be even better?

## Simpler Code in `addItem()`

Since you don't need to remember the variables, you can simplify the code.

Your code:

```
private TreeNode addItem(TreeNode root, int item) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new TreeNode(null, item, null);
        return root;
    } else {
        if (item < root.element) {
            if (root.left == null) {
                TreeNode node = addItem(root.left, item);
                root.left = node;
            } else {
                addItem(root.left, item);
            }
        } else if (item > root.element) {
            if (root.right == null) {
                TreeNode node = addItem(root.right, item);
                root.right = node;
            } else {
                addItem(root.right, item);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Duplicate Item");
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Simplified code:

```
private TreeNode addItem(TreeNode root, int item) {
    if (root == null)
        return new TreeNode(null, item, null);
    else if (item < root.element)
        if (root.left == null)
            root.left = addItem(root.left, item);
        else
            addItem(root.left, item);
    else if (item > root.element)
        if (root.right == null)
            root.right = addItem(root.right, item);
        else
            addItem(root.right, item);
    else
        System.out.println("Duplicate Item");
    return root;
}
```

And since the recursive `addItem()` is called anyway and checking `root` for `null` anyway, it can be even simpler:

```
private TreeNode addItem(TreeNode root, int item) {
    if (root == null)
        return new TreeNode(null, item, null);
    else if (item < root.element)
        root.left = addItem(root.left, item);
    else if (item > root.element)
        root.right = addItem(root.right, item);
    else
        System.out.println("Duplicate Item");
    return root;
}
```

## Use `stderr` instead of `stdout` for error messages

Your error message

```
        System.out.println("Duplicate Item");
```

should not go to `stdout` but to `stderr`, I guess.

```
        System.err.println("Duplicate Item");
```

## Use the *Visitor* pattern?

In `printPreOrderTree`, `printInOrderTree` and `printPostOrderTree`, you always visit all nodes.

The recursion over the nodes is always the same. What differs is the event placement and the action.

If your code gets more complex and you have more such recursions over the tree, you might want to use the *Visitor* design pattern to separate the recursion from the action to be performed with the node.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tiny note: Your

```
            if (root.left == null) {
                TreeNode node = addItem(root.left, item);
                root.left = node;
            } else {
                addItem(root.left, item);
            }
```

is a bit confusing as you're passing `root.left` which you know is `null`. As pointed in the other answer, the local variable adds no value.

So I'd go for

```
            if (root.left == null) {
                root.left = addItem(root.left, item);
            } else {
                addItem(root.left, item);
            }
```

---

But I guess that just

```
            root.left = addItem(root.left, item);
```

without any conditions should work as well (in case `root.left` is not `null`, the assignment does nothing). This may cost a little speed, but without a need for optimizations, I'd go for it.